# How can I mock final inner class here

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

**Class for which I m writing Junits:**

```
public class AImpl implements AInterface {
     public String method1(String id) throws Exception {

     String s = Service.Factory.getInstance().generate(id);
     return s;
  }
}
```

**Interface to be instantiated using its Inner class:**

```
public interface Service {

    String generate(String var1) throws Exception;

    public static final class Factory {
        private static Service instance = null;

        public Factory() {
        }

        public static final Service getInstance() {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = (Service)EnterpriseConfiguration.getInstance().loadImplementation(Service.class);
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried powerMockito but it is not working.

```
@Test
public void generateTest() throws Exception {
   Service.Factory innerClassMock = mock(Service.Factory.class);
   String id= "id";        
   whenNew(Service.Factory.class).withArguments(anyString()).thenReturn(innerClassMock);
   whenNew(innerClassMock.getInstance().generate("hjgh")).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(id);
   id= AImpl.generate("hjgh");
   Assert.assertEquals("id", id);
}
```

Comment: `it is not working` is a rather broad statement. It does not tell us what is actually happening as apposed to what was expected.

Comment: Refactor your productive code in order to be easier testable, i.e. do not use the static inner classes only having static methods. Use something like a singleton pattern where you can inject the mocked instance.

Comment: The code doesn't compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well your not cleary code you need this junit:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Service.Factory.class})
public class AImplTest {

    private Service serviceMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Service.Factory.class);
        serviceMock = Mockito.mock(Service.class);
        PowerMockito.when(Service.Factory.getInstance()).thenReturn(serviceMock);
    }

    @Test
    public void generateTest() throws Exception {
        Mockito.doReturn("mockid").when(serviceMock).generate(Mockito.anyString());
        Assert.assertEquals("mockid", new AImpl().method1("aaa"));
    }
}
```

Here my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.28.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-module-junit4 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Having said that I would change your Service.Factory class: here you need a private constructor in order to implement correctly the singleton pattern.

Comment: HI Renato, First of all thank you so much for solution. But I a, getting this error on executing the test case :

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.mockito.internal.configuration.ClassPathLoader

 at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.<clinit>(MockUtil.java:21)
 at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.scanner.MockScanner.<init>(MockScanner.java:22)
 at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.injectMocks(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:96)
 at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.configuration.PowerMockitoInjectingAnnotationEngine.process(PowerMockitoInjectingAnnotationEngine.java:40)
 at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler

Comment: Can you please suggest the possible solution.

Comment: Are you sure that your dependencies are the same? I run the code solution without any problem ...

Comment: Thanks Renato, I worked perfectly. I was using extra dependency mockito-core..which was causing an error. Removing it worked my test case.